# Redirect login page when click on forget password link meteor accounts

Tags: node.js, meteor, account, meteor-accounts

I am using accounts package of the meteor. I am facing the issue in forgot the password. I got a mail for reset password and when I click on this link then it redirects to login template instead to reset passwords.

```
      Template.forgotpassword.events({  
        'submit form': function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.type == "submit" || event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var forgotEmail = $('#forgotEmail').val();
                Accounts.forgotPassword({ email: forgotEmail }, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('err', err)
                        toastr.error(err.reason)
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Password reset link sent on registered email')
                        console.log('res', res);
                    }
                });
            };
        },
     });
    Template.ResetPassword.events({
        'submit #resetPasswordForm': function(e, t) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var resetPasswordForm = $(e.currentTarget),
                password = resetPasswordForm.find('#resetPasswordPassword').val(),
                passwordConfirm = resetPasswordForm.find('#resetPasswordPasswordConfirm').val();
            if (isNotEmpty(password) && areValidPasswords(password, passwordConfirm)) {
                Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetPassword'), password, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Your password has been changed. Welcome back!');
                        Session.set('resetPassword', null);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Email link like this:

```
        Hello,          
        To reset your password, simply click the link below.
        http://localhost:3000/#/reset-password/3FekfZRVG1W5IiBFm0_rFwCAi3wmt74AQNUp2Dyamf
        Thanks.
```

Router Configuration like this

```
        Router.route('/#/reset-password/:token', function() {
            this.render('ResetPassword');
            this.layout('blankLayout')
        });
```

Templates:

```
    <template name="ResetPassword">
        <div class="middle-box animated fadeInDown login-page"> <img class="blanckLogo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
            <form id="reset-password" name="reset-password">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="loginEmail">Enter New Password</label>
                    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"> </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-default" id="login" value="Update Password"> </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template name="forgotpassword">
        <div class="middle-box animated fadeInDown login-page"> <img class="blanckLogo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
            <form id="forgotForm" name="forgotForm">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="loginEmail">Enter email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="loginEmail" id="forgotEmail" class="form-control"> <span class="help-block m-b-none p-w-sm">Enter a valid Email</span> </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-default" id="login" value="Forgot Password"> </div>
                <div class="form-group"> <a class="btn-outline" href="/login">Back to login</a> </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing '/#' by adding the following to your accounts config:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {    
    Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword = {
     html(user, uri) {
      uri = uri.replace('#/', '');
      return "Click link below to reset password:\n" + uri;
     }
    };
  });
}
```

Also update your route from `/#/reset-password/:token` to `/reset-password/:token`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I am new in meteor can you please tell me in which templates I have to add this.

Comment: Updated the code, you can add it to your Meteor.startup.

Comment: No, it's not working. I update code above. can you please check it again. Thanks in advance

Comment: @VishnuChauhan Do you have ''blankLayout' defined somewhere? If not, remove the line and see if it works.